# Logic soundness and completeness

Tags: logic, incompleteness

I have to do a number of similar type questions, but I am having trouble grasping the general concepts around soundness and completeness. I have read up on the general definitions and think I understand them, but when asked to show something like the following I come up blank. Thanks for any ideas/help.

Show that the following propositional proof system, PCa, is sound but not complete.

PCa

Connectives (and constants) ∨, ∧, →, ↔, ¬, 0, 1

Axioms All tautologies of the form F→F

Rules of inference Hypothetical Syllogism

Answer (score 1):

See the following post about [Sound and complete](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/698441/sound-and-complete)

About your problem, I assume that you know the definition of *tautology*.

So you must show that :

> *(i)* your *axiom* $F \rightarrow F$ is a tautology

and that :

> *(ii)* your *rule of inference* preserve truth, i.e. if the premise is *true* also the conclusion is.

These two steps amount at a proof of the *soundness* of your calculus.

About the *completeness* side, you must show that

> *(iii)* your *calculus* is not complete.

This amount to finding a *tautology* that is not *derivable* (i.e.provable) from the axiom using only your rule of inference.

Comment: thanks for the quick response. Yes I do know what a tautology is. i) and ii) seem easy, even trivial in many cases. iii) Is where I am having the most trouble I guess. I can easily prove this system is sound, but am having problems with the completeness part. I also have other problems where I must prove that the system is complete which seems equally as difficult.

Comment: @user114620 - I think that a tautology that you cannot prove is $\lnot \lnot p \rightarrow p$. The problem is to find a way to prove that you *cannot* prove it. The usual technique to show independence result is through many-valued truth-tables. See Elliott Mendelson, *Introduction to Mathematical Logic* (4th ed - 1997), page 43.